Spring Boot 3.3.4 Healthcheck - [Error 59] no such command: 'hello'
I migrated an app from Springboot version 3.3.3 to version 3.3.4.
All unit test run correctly except the unit test Healthcheck (/actuator/health).
This test was running with no problem on Spring boot 3.3.3.
The mongo embeded I use in my project:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.bwaldvogel</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.44.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- METRICs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${version.spring-webmvc}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

The junit class I run:
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.xxx.xxx.api.absenceservice.config.ConnectionConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConnectionConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class MetricsTest {
    
    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext context;
    
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void shouldCheckHealthcheck() throws Exception {
        final String url = "/actuator/health";

        this.mockMvc.perform(get(url).header("Content-Type", "application/json"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(response -> {
                    final Map<String, String> metricsResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.getResponse().getContentAsString(), Map.class);
                    Assertions.assertEquals("UP", metricsResponse.get("status"));
                });
    }
}

The error I get is:
2024-10-17T09:07:38.808+02:00 ERROR 26448 --- [-server-worker3] d.b.mongo.backend.AbstractMongoDatabase  : unknown query: {"hello" : 1, "$db" : "test"}
2024-10-17T09:07:38.819+02:00 ERROR 26448 --- [-server-worker3] d.b.mongo.wire.MongoWireProtocolHandler  : failed to handle {"hello" : 1, "$db" : "test"}

de.bwaldvogel.mongo.exception.NoSuchCommandException: [Error 59] no such command: 'hello'
    at de.bwaldvogel.mongo.backend.AbstractMongoDatabase.handleCommand(AbstractMongoDatabase.java:181) ~[mongo-java-server-core-1.44.0.jar:na]
    at de.bwaldvogel.mongo.backend.AbstractMongoBackend.handleCommand(AbstractMongoBackend.java:339) ~[mongo-java-server-core-1.44.0.jar:na]
    at de.bwaldvogel.mongo.backend.AbstractMongoBackend.handleMessage(AbstractMongoBackend.java:412) ~[mongo-java-server-core-1.44.0.jar:na]
    at de.bwaldvogel.mongo.wire.MongoDatabaseHandler.handleMessage(MongoDatabaseHandler.java:73) ~[mongo-java-server-core-1.44.0.jar:na]
    at de.bwaldvogel.mongo.wire.MongoDatabaseHandler.channelRead0(MongoDatabaseHandler.java:62) ~[mongo-java-server-core-1.44.0.jar:na]
    at de.bwaldvogel.mongo.wire.MongoDatabaseHandler.channelRead0(MongoDatabaseHandler.java:27) ~[mongo-java-server-core-1.44.0.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:868) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.113.Final.jar:4.1.113.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-10-17T09:07:38.837+02:00  WARN 26448 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator  : MongoDB health check failed

The 'hello' healthcheck was intorduced in mongoDB since version 5.0!
If you guys have an idea would be strongly appreciated...

Perhaps you need a newer mongo-java-server?

@joe I upgraded mongo-java-server to latest version (1.45.0) but still the same error :-/

For anyone facing the same problem:
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.bwaldvogel</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.45.0</version>
</dependency>

is not compatible yet with MongoDB hello command.
MONGODB  isMaster command
since MongoDB 4.0
spring-boot-actuator  3.2.3
Deprecated since version MongoDB 4.4.2
driver-mongodb-sync 4.11.1
org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator
Document result = this.mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ isMaster: 1 }");  // in doHealthCheck

totally removed in spring-boot-actuator 3.3.3
MONGODB  hello command
Is now used in spring-boot-actuator >= 3.3.3
driver-mongodb-sync 5.0.1
org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator
Document result = this.mongoTemplate.executeCommand("{ hello: 1 }");  // in doHealthCheck

Hop this will help you.
